# Creating a Generic Type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I had a problem with generic types. I have a user defined type(interface) like this:

```
IList1: {  
          prop1: string,  
          prop2: number,  
          prop3: string  
          .  
          .  
          . 
       }

IList2:...
IList3:...
```

and after some serverside response, I get response in the type of **Array<Array<,IListx>>**. So I tried to create a function like this:

```
function fun<T>(args:T):Array<Array<T>> {
  return Array<Array<typeof args>>;
}
```

and variables like this:

```
let a:fun<IList1> = ...;
let b:fun<IList2> = ...;
let x:fun<IListx> = ...;
```

This didn't work. Also I'm not sure this is the correct way of creating a generic type. I know I did something wrong but couldn't find the proper solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After some trials, I think I found a way by both defining and initializing:

```
function fun<T>():Array<Array<T>> {
  return Array<Array<T>>();
}


let a= fun<IList1>();
let b= fun<IList2>();
```

worked as expected. I don't know if there are possible better solutions.